# How can I refactor my code (laravel, OOP)

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I finished some small app using laravel, it works, but I have some kind of spaghetti code. I would like to ask your help. I have some theory about code patterns, but I do not have idea how to implement them in my case.

The most weird part: I have input data that should be analyzed step by step and some actions needs to be taken. For example I have an input an array with parameters

```
$array = ['param1','param2','param3', ..., 'paramN']
```

I need to analyze it from param1 to paramN and take some actions. Code structure looks like:

```
if($array['param1'] == 'X') {
    some action
} else { return ....}

if($array['param2'] == 'Y') {
    some action
} else { 
    if($array['param3'] == 'Z') {
        return ....
    } else { return ....}
}
```

This code includes uses some Facades, Validation in `if` blocks, but the number of `if`s is terrible. But it's business logic.

Maybe you can give me an idea in which way I can reorganize my code to make it more clear?

Answer (score 1):

you can use collection to refactor your logic with a very good readable code the above code can be look like below

```
$array = ['param1','param2','param3', ..., 'paramN'];
$collection = collect($array);
```

now define your processing as callback

```
$param1Callback = function($value) {
     // $value will be value of param1 which is X in your comparision so write your if logic here
     if($value == 'x') {
        // process here 
        return true;
     }
     return false;
}
$callbacks = ['param1' => $param1Callback, 'param2' => $param2Callback ...];

$collection->each(function($value, $key) use($callbacks){
    if($callbacks[$key]($value)) {
        // here param1 value is processed with 'X' and that callback returned true
    }
... and so on
});
```

hopefully you get the idea here is the full documentation about available methods of collections.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#available-methods

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply!
This logic is good if I need to return true or false. But sometimes I need to return view with message to user. And processing of some parameters depends on previous result of processing some other parameters. I'm afraid this approach will not suitable for me. Or am I wrong?

Comment: for better understanding of collection have a look at adam's course its too good for collection and will fit in all kind of requirement.
https://adamwathan.me/refactoring-to-collections/